# Choose a specific app to open a particular file

Tags: applications

I created some e-learning using Articulate Storyline 2 which I want to view on my Samsung Galaxy. The files are physically in my Documents folder. The module is not on the internet - I'm still testing it. The file to run the e-learning module is "story.html." It will - I'm told - run on Android with the use of a free app called Articulate Player - which I have installed. When I attempt to run the "story.html" file I get three options - "HTML Viewer," "File Editor" and "DB Text Editor," none of which work. Articulate Player app is not provided as an option. So how can I choose Articulate Player app to run the "html.story" file?

I've looked in applications manager but there are no options I can see that help.

I must add, please pardon my ignorance as I know next to nothing about mobile phones. I have avoided them like the plague for years and only got this one recently as a matter of necessity. I would be grateful for any help from anyone and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can only open files with apps that tell Android they support that kind of file. If the app tells Android it can open that kind of file, it'll show up in the list of possible apps.

If this app you mention can open this kind of file, the developer needs to change the app to tell Android it can do so, by adding an *intent filter* in its *manifest*. You should contact the developer and ask them to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The story.html file is supposed to open in your normal mobile browser, which will then open the Articulate Player app and load the content. Does the "html viewer" option open the real browser, or is it using a browser inside the file manager app? If the latter, then that's your problem methinks. Try opening the story.html file from Chrome or the stock Browser and see if that works. Also, [read this](http://www.articulate.com/support/storyline-2/how-to-distribute-articulate-storyline-content-for-flash-html5-and-articulate-mobile-player-sl2) as it explains how the content gets loaded onto the client and may help. BTW, you need to specify AMP support when you published the content or else it won't try to use the player at all.

Comment: Thanks to Dan Hulme and apraetor for your responses. Appreciated. To the latter, I know this will sound dumb but how would I open the file in Chrome or navigate to it's location? This android stuff is really new territory for me.

Comment: Ah, sorted! Downloaded Open In Browser app which lets me choose which browser I want to open a file. And it now works. Again, thanks for your input as it certainly put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Choose "send /share" and select the app you want to open the file with